# Create function with dblink and concat escape

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, select, return

I'm using postgreSQL (pgadmin 3) to create a function using dblink and concat ESCAPE in select ...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.crm_layout_1100()
  RETURNS TABLE (layout_1100 text)
  AS $func$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM dblink('CONNECTION STRING',
                             'SELECT ''RETURN_1'' ||E''\t''|| ''RETURN_2''') as link
                            (LAYOUT_1100 varchar);
    END;
$func$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When i execute the script, the result in postgres is:

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 8:                     'SELECT ''CUSTOMER_ID'' ||E''\t''|| ''RE...
                            ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 8:                     'SELECT ''CUSTOMER_ID'' ||E''\t''|| ''RE...
                            ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.

Query returned successfully with no result in 13 msec.
```

The script above, is only an **example** of my need, is basically return "VALUE_1" **ESCAPE** "VALUE_2" from a table ...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I cannot reproduce your error. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Lukasz, in 'dblink' change CONNECTION STRING with your information, for security, i have removed the connections

Comment: I did that and also fixed return type (_varchar returned, text expected_) but I still do not get your error. Function executes successfully.